# how to create a php file using another php file inside your webhost

Tags: php

I've created a php file that creates another php file,
heres the code:

```html
if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
$name=$_POST['name'];
$string = '<?php
echo "'. $_POST["message"]. '";

?>
';
$fp = fopen("$name.php", "w");

fwrite($fp, $string);

fclose($fp);

}
```

it successfully created a php file using xampp in my local machine,
but when i upload it to my webhosting site, everytime i click submit, it doesnt create any file i written.
I dont get what is wrong with it,
somebody said that i need to connect it to my ftp server,
but i dont get it. 
Advance thanks guys for the help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Usually, you don't need to create a new php file to echo out a name. At worst, If I couldn't use any database I would store the name in a txt or something. Also, this is extremely vulnerable to code injection (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Code_Injection ).

Comment: ow.. is that so.. i want to create a page for my parents everyday, so i decided to make a php file to create another and it is linked to the index, so when i have created a file successfully using this, i dont need to create another file with so many codes in it and i will just edit the index and add a href. sorry for my bad english,.

Answer (score 0):

Check your rigths on a dir where you want to save the file. It must be 664.

Comment: is it in the webhosting? where can i find it?

Comment: Yes. You can access it via webftp or some other web interfaces for ftp. Or via ftp client.

Comment: Forgot... You must set filename relative to server root dir. Check the manual http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php

Comment: tried changing privelages. but still no luck on adding anew file. Thanks sir for helping. i really appriciated that..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 3 things to solve here. 
1) File permission 
2) Rewriting a file
3) I thing there is an error on your line with $string because you are already in a php code

Try this

```
<?php
//If the form is submited
if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) 
{
//we parse the informations
$name=addslashes($_POST['name']);
$string = addslashes($_POST["message"]);

//We will recreate the file even if it was existing 
$fp = fopen("$name.php", "w+");

fwrite($fp, $string);

fclose($fp);

//We give access permission to the file
chmod("$name.php", 0777);

}
?>
```

And also if you are creating the file in a  directory, use your ftp software like  [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) to connect to your ftp and right click on the directory and click on Chmod. Make a Chmod 0777 on that directory. And everything should work fine.

**Submit verification**

Now if still it does not work, you can search bit by bit for the error by creating a file name **test.php** with this code

```
<?php
//we parse the informations

$name='my_one_file';

$string = '<h1>It is working<h1>';

//We will recreate the file even if it was existing 
$fp = fopen("$name.php", "w+");

fwrite($fp, $string);

fclose($fp);

//We give access permission to the file
chmod("$name.php", 0777);

echo "<a href='$name.php' target='_blank'> <h1> $name.php</h1> </a>";
?>
```

And then you launch yourwebsite/test.php in your browser. If it works you should have a file name *my_one_file.php* on your server. If it shows a link then the problem is with your **if (isset($_POST["Submit"]))**. Meaning we have to cross check your **html form**.

**Touch Verification**

Finaly if it is still not working then we can verify if the file needs to be created first on your server before being modified like some server do.
For that you will still create a test.php file with the following code

```
<?php

$name='my_one_file';

$string = 'My message';

touch("$name.php"); 


//We will recreate the file even if it was existing 
$fp = fopen("$name.php", "w+");

fwrite($fp, $string);

fclose($fp);

//We give access permission to the file
chmod("$name.php", 0777);

echo "<a href='$name.php' target='_blank'> <h1> $name.php</h1> </a>";
?>
```

And then lauch yourwebsite/test.php. If it works you should have a file name *my_one_file.php* on your server.

Comment: still not adding a file sir. I dont know why. i just copy your code but still no luck. but thanks for helping.

Comment: @Hoodedwarlock  I have modified the code and added other code in case the first code that i have modified is still not working. Try those one and let us know what happens.

Comment: sir, it creates a link my_one_file.php, and when i clicked it, it says page not found. does that mean that the error is in my form?

Comment: @Hoodedwarlock   The error may be with your form or with your server. Which version of php are you using ? Try to create another_test.php file with the following `<?php if(touch('my_text.txt')) { echo "<h1>  The problem is NOT with my server </h1>"; } else { echo "<h1>  The problem is  with my server </h1>"; }  ?>` and launch that page. That page may tell you whether the problem is with your server or not.

Comment: Create a file named test.php and put in the code i just gave you in my previous comment. That will help us know whether the problem is with your server or not